# All IBOutlets are nil in my main scene

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder, watchkit

On a Watch app, all my `@IBOutlet` variables are nil during the `willActivate` in my main scene.

I have a page-based application, and the other scenes are working fine, but my main scene finds all `@IBOutlet` to be nil. The weirdest part is that it was working fine until at some point, I don't know why, everything started to be nil.

I tried setting them to either `weak` or not, but this didn't change anything. They are not custom elements, only `WKInterfaceLabel`, `WKIntefaceGroup` and things like that.

The declarations are like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var gamesTable: WKInterfaceTable!
@IBOutlet weak var livesGroup: WKInterfaceGroup!
@IBOutlet weak var livesLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var coinsLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var livesTimer: WKInterfaceTimer!
```

They seem correctly linked in Xcode, and I tried cleaning/restarting Xcode:

[image: Xcode outlet links screenshot]

Comment: Try moving your code to awakeWithContext, as in this method, you are guaranteed that the objects will not be nil if you have them connected properly (this is called when all objects are ready).

Comment: I tried that, but it's still the same. I also tried adding a log directly in the `awakeWithContext` and it is nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason why all this was happening. It is very specific to the Apple Watch.

Basically, my elements were not "installed" on 38mm Apple Watch. At one point, I had set my Xcode to 42mm Apple Watch because I wanted to tweak some things in this specific size, and I ended moving groups around and so on.

What happened is that all the things I changed didn't happen in 38, so back in 38 everything was here, but the "installed" checkbox wasn't checked, and the scene was basically empty on a 38mm Apple Watch, which I hadn't noticed.

Comment: Thank you! This was a such a specific issue I couldn't, for the life of me, figure out.